# Find matrices given sums of each row and column with bounded integer entries: maximize zero-valued entries

Tags: matrices, integer-programming, network-flow

I want to find solutions for the following problem. It seems to be a classic problem in integer programmimg and logistics, but I don't know its name.

**Find a matrix of m rows and n columns, with non-negative entries, such that the sum of the entries in each row are, respectively, m given integers and the sum of the entries in each column are, also respectively, another n given integers.**

**Also, the entries will be limited to given maximum integers, and in some cases those entries will be 0.**

In reality, I am interested in an algorithm for extracting all solutions (maybe I should ask in the Programming StackExchange if this is not the correct place). In the end, my goal is to find a solution which makes the **maximum possible number of entries equal to zero**.

This problem comes from allocating teachers (columns) for classes on days (rows) so that they come to work the least possible number of days (the non-zero entries).

Just to have a better idea of the sizes of each parameter: m=5, n=100, entries are bounded to 5 or 6, when not set to 0 from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r_i$ be the required sum for row $i$, and let $c_j$ be the required sum for column $j$. Let nonnegative integer variable $x_{i,j}$ with upper bound $M_{i,j}$ be the entry in cell $(i,j)$, and let binary variable $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether $x_{i,j}>0$.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i,j} (1 - y_{i,j})$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{i,j} &= r_i &&\text{for all $i$}\\
\sum_i x_{i,j} &= c_j &&\text{for all $j$}\\
x_{i,j} &\le M_{i,j} y_{i,j} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$}
\end{align}

If you think of the equivalent objective of minimizing $\sum_{i,j} y_{i,j}$, this is the *fixed-charge transportation problem* in a complete bipartite network with a supply node for each $i$, a demand node for each $j$, and arcs $(i,j)$ with capacity $M_{i,j}$.  In this formulation, "set to $0$ from the beginning" means $M_{i,j}=0$, but it is more efficient to just omit that arc.